# Using good method to produce a regular matrix

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

The matrixform is as follow, and how can I use good method to produce it?[image]

```
H = {{1, 1, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 1},
     {0, 2, 2}, {1, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 2}}
```

Comment: If the picture can't show,then here is the matrixform:H={{1,1,0},{2,2,0},{0,1,1},{0,2,2},{1,0,1},{2,0,2}}

Comment: `KroneckerProduct[
 MapThread[
  ReplacePart[#1, #2 -> 0] &, {ConstantArray[1, {3, 3}], 
   RotateRight[Range[3]]}],
 {{1}, {2}}
 ]`

Comment: Great,thank you very much!

Comment: Or `Normal@KroneckerProduct[
  SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1, 
    Band[{3, 1}] -> 1}, {3, 3}],
  {{1}, {2}}
  ]`.

Comment: If these methods are "good" lies in the eye of the beholder. Maybe you can try to be a bit more specific? Probably you want to generalize the matrix patter to higher matrix dimensions?

Comment: Fine,it's not as easy as I thought.

Comment: Yeah,then I will use map to generalize the matrix patter to higher matrix dimensions.

Comment: `Transpose@KroneckerProduct[Permutations[{1, 0, 1}], {1, 2}]`

Comment: Good!Thank you！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice tool for this job is `ArrayFlatten[ ]`

```
a = {{1}, {2}}
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Not sure why your rows are ordered the way they are. Are you trying to have a non-zero diagonal?

```
{{a,a,0},{0,a,a},{a,0,a}}// ArrayFlatten
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 2 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 2 & 2 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 2 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: This is not the exact result the OP is asking. The order of the elements is different. Also the "permutation" solution is already posted in my answer

Comment: My purpose was to introduce `ArrayFlatten`. Not enough info to algorithmically determine the order of perms.

Comment: Actually,this is the answer I originally wanted,then I will use  ''PauliMatrix'' and  ''Map'' to get what I want.Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
IntegerDigits[{12,24,4,8,10,20},3,3]
```

> {{1,1,0},{2,2,0},{0,1,1},{0,2,2},{1,0,1},{2,0,2}}

also..

```
s = Transpose[Permutations /@ {{1, 1, 0}, {2, 2, 0}}];
Flatten[{{s[[1]]},Reverse@Rest@s},2]
```

> {{1,1,0},{2,2,0},{0,1,1},{0,2,2},{1,0,1},{2,0,2}}

Comment: I like the answer,thanks!

Comment: @KarryMa Alternatively to `PadLeft` you can add `3` as 3rd argument `IntegerDigits[{12, 24, 4, 8, 10, 20}, 3, 3]`.

Comment: yes, you are so right!